# Android MPAndroidChart Text Overlapping with PieChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPAndroidChart` for showing values in `PieChart`.

I Refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969952/setdescriptiontextsizefloat-size-cannot-resolve-method-mpandroidchart) but still am not clear to fix text overlapping in `PieChart`
Below image am getting as result.

The orange value contains 3, it showing at bottom, but green value contains 2, it not showing up properly. Solution needs for green value.

[image]

```
    chart.setUsePercentValues(false);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getDescription().setTextSize(25f);
    chart.setExtraOffsets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    chart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.95f);

    chart.setCenterTextTypeface(tfLight);
    chart.setCenterTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    chart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    chart.setHoleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBar));

    chart.setTransparentCircleColor(R.color.toolBar);
    chart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(110);

    chart.setHoleRadius(35f);
    //  chart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);
    chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    chart.setDrawCenterText(true);

    chart.setRotationAngle(0);
    // enable rotation of the chart by touch
    chart.setRotationEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
```

Can Anyone help me out from this issue, where my code went wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which text are you referring to?

Comment: Outside of `pieChart` value, on green color text value 2 overlapping with piechart.

Comment: and the orange 3?

Comment: Orange value contains 3, it showing at bottom. But Green value contains 2, it not showing up properly. Solution needs for Green value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution by adding below lines to avoid overlapping text with `pieChart`,

```
PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
dataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(90.f); 
dataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(.10f);
dataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(.50f);
```

Getting result like below,

[image]